# android native code call java method success, but ui method failed

Tags: android, java-native-interface, listener

I success go the flow of native call java method, 
but when the java method contains ui method, ui method always failed, 
and logcat will print VM aborting error:

```
E/ListenerTest( 1399): virtual void JNIListenerContext::postEv(int32_t)
W/dalvikvm( 1399): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
W/dalvikvm( 1399):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run:()V (CallStaticVoidMethodV)
W/dalvikvm( 1399): Pending exception is:
I/dalvikvm( 1399): "Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm( 1399):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x413f0b98 self=0x89b7e8
I/dalvikvm( 1399):   | sysTid=1411 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8998000
I/dalvikvm( 1399):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
I/dalvikvm( 1399):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 1399):
E/dalvikvm( 1399): VM aborting
```

In my native code:

```
JNIEnv *env = AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv();
env->CallStaticVoidMethod( jclass, jmethod, arg);// call java method postEv(arg)
```

In my java code:

```
class ListenerClass {
    ... ...
    private static Listener mListener = null;
    public interface Listener {
        public void onMyListener( int arg );
    }

    public void registerListener (Listener listener) {
        Log.d( TAG,"registerListener");
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static void postEv( int arg ) {
        Log.d( TAG,"postEv");
        if( mListener != null ) {
            mListener.onMyListener( arg );
        } else {
            Log.d( TAG,"no Listener");
        }
    }
}

public class ListenerDemo extends Activity implements ListenerClass.Listener
    ... ...
    private TextView info;
    private ListenerClass lisener = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        info.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        info.setTextSize(20);

        info.setText("haha");  // this works

        lisener = new ListenerClass();

        Log.d( TAG,"lisener.registerListener");
        lisener.registerListener(this);

    }

    public void onMyListener( int arg ) {
        Log.d(TAG,"arg is: " + arg );  // this works
        info.setText("haha");  // this not works
    }
    ... ...
}
```

I really don't know why this happaned.
And I want the TextView to show, when an event has push to java's onMyListener.

Comment: In your native code, how do you get the parameters you pass to java (jclass, jmethod, arg)

Comment: jclass jclaz = env->FindClass(path);
jmethodID jmed = env->GetStaticMethodID( jclaz, "postEv", "(I)V" );
int arg = 123;
Anyway, these parameters have no problem, because the java method onMyListener has been called successed.
Only the ui method ( info.setText("haha") ) failed.
If there is no ui method, the java method will return success.

Comment: From the log, there looks to be a pending Exception from JNI. Confirm that each of the parameters is not null, before calling the java method

Comment: sorry, but i mean: if my onMyListener( int arg ) has only one sentence Log.d(TAG,"arg is: " + arg), then everything is ok. So all the parameters are not null. The problem occured when there is a ui method like info.setText.

Comment: I suspect that you are seeing an exception which happened earlier, which just becomes visible when you call setText.  My policy is always to suspect my own code first :-)

Comment: You're true. I believe so. But I just can't figure out. And at last, I use Handler.setEmptyMessage in onMyListener to let another function to do ui method and it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I found the reason why ui method can not be called.

My Native Call Java uses CallStaticVoidMethod(...), which means class method.

"private TextView info" is none static, which means object variable.

Although onMyListener is none static, it can use none static member info.

**Native static method -> Java none-static method -> Java none-static variable seems ok.
=>
Native static method --> Java none-static variable is not ok.**

You can't use object variable in class method.
The reason is very clear but the jni process hide the reason.

My good job! 
At the beginning I doubt this static use, today i try CallVoidMethod and it success.

Comment: I faced similar issue but I am using jni _NewObjectA_ to call java non static method. I believe env->NewObjectA is non static method, but Application crashes when doing ui activity in call. Now after setting my TextView to static, Application doesn't crash but sets text only one time after periodic java calling thread ceases!